# why virt in top different from vmsize in /proc/pid/status

Tags: linux, memory-management

when I run `top -p pid`, virt shows that my program use 4T virtual-memory. But by `cat /proc/pid/status`, vmsize is more than 20T. I think virt in top should equal to vmsize. So what's the difference between virt in top and vmsize in procfs? (By the way , when I run `statsize=1 top -p pid`, virt shows that my program use 80T+ virtual-memory)